# How to express object return type based on input value in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What's the correct syntax to use for the following (maximally simplified) function:

```
function f(field: string): ??? {
    return {[field]: 42};
}
```

The output shape of this function is always:

```
f('foo') => {foo: 42}
f('blah') => {blah: 42}
f('a-okay') => {"a-okay": 42}
f('') => {"": 42}
```

Is there a syntax or a special $Utility function available to help me express the output type for this function?  Is it possible at all?

For the record, I'm never invoking this function with a dynamic value, i.e.

```
let x = random_string();
f(x)
```

Instead, I'm only ever using this function with string literals (constants), like in the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot require the result object to have a *specific* key that is only known when the function is called, but you can do a type check with an [*indexer property*](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps):

```
function f(field: string): { [string]: number } {
    return {[field]: 42};
}
```